# Handle many requests Web Services

Tags: tomcat, java

I created a web service with Jersey and Tomcat in localhost.

Now I want to expose my web services to all users in the world, so let's assume you have many concurrent requests.

I have access to a good physical blade server (4 CPU (8 cores)-32GB RAM, 600GB HD, etc. ..), only one.

I'm wondering, with a single physical server load balancing is useful? or proxy reserve? or only when you have multiple physical servers?

How should I manage the architecture with Tomcat and Jersey?

What are the possible solutions to handle many requests? pool of threads? but how i can do that with Jersey?

Comment: Will groups of users get to see identical results? If so, have you considered `varnish` etc? Say you have a service that has a backend and frontend and only the backend requires login, only backend users would have to be served from Tomcat, the frontend users could get to see a cached page and the cache could age according to your (and the service's) needs. Also, the question is a bit open-ended as it stands. It might lead to a discussion rather than Q&A-style answers.

Comment: no the result sometimes is different, i have for client an app android, and for server(tomcat+jersey). My problem now is figure out how i can handle many requests concurrent?. Example 100 user use my app for retrive something from db, how i can handle that? i think a thread pool but i'm not sure

Comment: Well, but even if those 100 users use the app instead of a browser you probably don't want Tomcat (and a backend DB) to do the work all over again? `nginx` and `varnish` and `cherokee` to my knowledge have all solved the 10k problem. But that's *just* concurrent connections. Why would you want all content generated anew? All big Internet firms use an elaborate network of caching and sharding (DB) to cater all their visitors.

Comment: You will improve availability having two instances even on same machine, much better to scale this way then trying to manage a monster instance which is using the whole heap and using all the CPU when stuck in a GC loop etc.  Key item missing in this question is if there is a datasource used.

Comment: two instances even on same machine of Tomcat? My architecture is: CLIENT app (android) --> SERVER webservices-tomcat (container) and mysql db

Comment: Yes it's possible.  Do some reading on CATALINA_HOME, CATALINA_BASE in the tomcat docs.  Pay attention to comment above about sharding on the DB, the DB and related I/O is key factor in handling loads of transactions.